# How do I use Quiver?

Tags: destiny

The Quiver perk says it allows you to fire Shadowshot up to three times per use. But I've never actually managed to make that happen yet. What am I missing? How do I trigger the extra shots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to fire multiple shots is to use the activate super command again while your super bar is still dropping. This differs from the probably more familiar golden gun in that it doesn't replace your standard weapon.

As Lasse has mentioned at time of writing this answer the perk has been disabled due to an exploit.

Answer (score 8):

As of right now, the Quiver perk is nonfunctional.

There is/was an exploit running rampant during last weeks Iron Banner event where clever use of the in-game menu could lead to near infinite number of Shadowshot usages once the super was attained.

Bungie has temporarily disabled the Quiver perk and will patch it back in in the (near) future when they have fixed the bug.

They cancelled the rollout of Trials of Osiris this past weekend because of this bug and the hope is that they will now roll Trials out the coming weekend, weekend of 31st of October to 2nd of November, with or without the patch for Quiver, but definitely without the glitch that made Hunters near invincible.

More information can be found in the [patch notes of for Destiny 2.0.1.2](https://www.bungie.net/en/News/News?aid=13775):

- Classes

  - Nightstalker Hunter

    > Temporarily removed the extra shots from Quiver to avoid unlimited Shadowshots
    >   This is a temporary fix, and the node will be restored in a fixed state in an upcoming patch

Since the glitch doesn't work any more it is safe to describe how it worked. Basically you gained your full super, then activated Shadowshot twice while it was counting down. Then, before the entire super energy had disappeared you quickly went into the character screen and out again. Hey, presto, full super again.

A video of the glitch can be seen here:

[Youtube: Infinite Shadow Shot Glitch - Destiny: The Taken King](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-Du9etjUyY)

Comment: A bit disappointing that they had to go to the extreme to work around an exploit, but I have to say the biggest frustration I have with it is that there's no in-game notice. Guess it was easier to just disable functionality and move on, than to bother giving the player any indication of why it's not working. Like all the lore in the Grimoire, this is something the player should *not* have to break away from the game to find out. :-(

Comment: @Iszi: It was in the patch notes and the weekly update https://www.bungie.net/7_Destiny-Hot-Fix---10202015/en/News/News?aid=13775 . It is annoying that there is no in game notification that it doesn't work but given the nature of the way it was done I suspect disabling it was quick, while disabling it and putting some kind of notice or warning in place would have been much slower and led to a lot of angry players on the receiving end of this exploit.